# How to get the exe name while the program is running

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the app name while my program initializes.

for eg. I have an exe called tempName.exe

How do I know get the tempName in my program? so instead of getting the parameter passed. I want the exe name.

Thank You
Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Process` class (`using System.Diagnostics`):

```
string name = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
```

or

```
string name = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
```

Comment: okay. this gives me the exe.  But the true exe name. I have shortcuts that are created that accesses this exe. but I need the shortcut name, of the shortcut selected to run

Comment: That's a very different question.

Comment: sorry If I phrased it wrong Codran

Comment: Lets try this again. I have one program, the exe is called main.exe. when main.exe is excuted. I allowed the user to be able to create a shortcut off main.exe. But when the user can create any name for the shortcut. so if the user is selecting the shortcut. I need the name of this short cut. not the program its pointing to

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways as pointed out in other answers.  One such way is following:

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
```

GetCommandLineArgs() returns the command line arguments as a list of strings for the current application.  0th element in the list is application name.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx) for more detail on the GetCommandLineArgs().

If you need to know which shortcut was used to run your application, you can do that creating a shortcut of your application with argument that denotes shortcut. For example yourapp.exe /s1 , yourapp.exe /s2 , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 string exeAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;
 string exeAssemblyName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Comment: This doesnt give me the short cut name. my program has a the functionality to create short cuts. but this doesnt give the short cut name on the exe that is selected on. it gives me the exe it is pointing to